# Where are postgresql aggregate functions stored?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, pgadmin-4

I have created an aggregate function and I can even use it. But I cannot find it under any of the DB hierarchies. It's not under Functions.

Are they hidden from view? I'm using pgAdmin ide.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-aggregate.html But: *why* do you want to know?

Comment: editing, viewing its makeup etc...

Comment: in psql : `\da[S]  [PATTERN]      list aggregates`

Comment: Aggregate functions gui not implemented in pgAdmin4, that's the reason it is not showing in Browser tree.

Comment: I am using pgadmin3 because I simply _hate_ pgadmin4, and aggregate functions are not visible there either.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to find such a query is to use psql with the --echo-hidden option. Then run the psql meta-command and you will see the query that is used

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  p.proname as "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
 CASE
  WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
  WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
  ELSE 'normal'
 END as "Type"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll save this one. I think it was the IDE (pgAdmin) I was using. I switched to DBeaver and I can see the Agg Function in the hierarchy.